# Is rm failing due to quotes in path?

Tags: bash, quotes

I am trying to empty a directory using the `rm` program. I capture a path into a variable and go to use this like so:

```
rm $export_folder_path
rm: “/Users/ricky/Documents/Folder”: No such file or directory
```

There certainly is such a directory at the path. When I try this manually, without a variable, it works as expected.

```
rm "/Users/ricky/Documents/Folder"
```

Comment: To remove a directory, you need to use `rmdir` or `rm -r`.  I wonder how just `rm` is removing the directory for you.  Can you paste the output of `ls -la /Users/ricky/Documents/Folder`?

Comment: Are you sure about that? `rm` won't delete a folder unless you give it the `-rf` options.If you're trying to delete the files inside the directory (and there aren't any directories inside the directory in question), then you can do that with `rm /Users/ricky/Documents/Folder/*`

Comment: Sorry @codeforester it isn't actually working yet, but I at least see an error about it being a directory.

Comment: You put curly quotes in `export_folder_path`. Don't do that.

Comment: use "straight" double-quotes, i.e. `"` . Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You're using fancy quotes in your assignment of `export_folder_path`. These slanted Unicode quotes are not recognized as quotes by bash, and are therefore treated as literals.

This is usually due to copypasting from blogs, or using an editor or OS not intended for programmers such as Word or macOS.

Replace them with regular ASCII double quotes in your script, and disable "smart quotes" in your editor or OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about removing the directory along with its contents, I would advise this:

```
rm -rf -- "$export_folder_path"
```

The double quotes will take care of any spaces in the name of the directory.